# Time complexity of dequeue operation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Consider the following operation along with Enqueue and Dequeue operations on queues, where k is a global parameter.

```
MultiDequeue(Q){
     m = k 
     while ((Q is not empty) and (m > 0))  
     { Dequeue(Q) 
       m = m – 1 
      }
}
```

What is the worst case time complexity of a sequence of n queue operations on an initially full  
queue?

(A) Θ(n)

(B) Θ(n+k)

(C) Θ(nk)

(D) Θ(n^2)

---

Here suppose we do one dequeue operation, then the loop will run for min(n,k) times. Now remaining 1 operation can be 1 enqueue operation which will take O(1) time so total complexity in this case will be O(min(n,k)).

Suppose we have k=1 and do (n-1) dequeue operations then it will take k*(n-1) time for multideqeue function and remaining one enqueue operation will take O(1) time . So in total we are getting O(kn) time in this case.

I am confused on how to handle 'k' parameter when we are calculating complexity.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question contains no "enqueue" operations, so it's unclear why these would matter. You also don't define what `n` is this story. Viewed in isolation, the loop runs at most `k` times, so it's linear time. In notations like `Θ(n)`, `n` is a parameter that is taken to be clear from context, but here it's not clear from context.

Comment: It can be any combination. You can call n times multi dequeue or (n-1) multi dequeue and 1 time normal enqueue/dequeue

Comment: But "what is the worst case time complexity of a sequence of `n` queue operations on an initially full queue?" Don't you mean a sequence of `n` *dequeue* operations? Queue operations on a full queue aren't possible, since, well, it's full.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it's clearly mentioned n is number of queue operations which can be enqueue/dequeue/multi-dequeue.

Comment: Oh, I see -- any *arbitrary* queue operation. That's an odd question, to say the least...

Comment: @JeroenMostert Also you can have any combination of operations. Who said that we have to enqueue on a full queue ?

Comment: The answer is `Θ(n+k)`: in the wost case, on a full queue, an initial `MultiDequeue` would take `k` steps, and any sequence on an empty queue cannot exceed `n`, because 1) no step can enqueue more than one element and 2) no step can dequeue more elements than there are in the queue at that moment. There's probably a nice formal proof here that I'm too lazy to write. (Hmm, wait, I may be wrong. The case where `k` is smaller than the initial size `N` of the queue must be considered. ...it's really a good textbook question. :-) Work it out with extreme values for `k` and `N`.)

Comment: Right, so `Θ(nk)`. Let `N` be the size of the initially full queue, and let it be 1 googolplex. Let `k` be `100`. Clearly, the worst case time for a sequence of `n` operations in this case is `n` `MultiDequeue` calls, each of which take `k` steps. (We assume `k > 0`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Actually that theta notation and k parameter is confusing there. Are you sure it would be theta(nk) ? . It can be O(nk) but i am not sure about theta

Comment: Theta = "exact" time, rather than time bounded from above (big O), see [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). `k` is just a parameter of the algorithm in this case, just like `n`. It has no special meaning, the complexity just depends on more than one parameter in this case. The time cannot be *less* than `nk` since worst case is being asked for, so we're allowed to pick the most time consuming sequence possible. (If `k = 0` is allowed, the worst case is `n`, since `MultiDequeue` is a no-op in that case, and so the theta can't apply.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hey, the answer is theta(n). https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/time-complexity-of-dequeue-function-queues

Comment: The answer assumes `k` is a constant, rather than an input parameter of the problem. This may well be what the person who composed the problem intended, but it's not made clear. It could have done with a more formal presentation. (Just saying "it's a global parameter" is not enough in my book.)

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site? (No.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) I'd suggest deleting this one, since it doesn't have an answer yet.

Comment: @Dukeling it's not allowed but you see that I got no answer plus one downvote here even though original question makes sense. So I had to post it on cs stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider 'K' as constant, and while calculating time complexity (asymptotically) we ignore such constant terms or count it as O(1).
So your worst time complexity for this program may go upto O(n).